# What is the name for items separated by commas without conjunctive?

Tags: grammar, commas

What is the name for constructions like the following, where the final conjunctive is omitted?

> He came, he saw, he conquered.
>
> The sirens were constant, loud, annoying.

I'm sure I heard this stylistic flourish given a proper name, but I can't remember where. I use this fairly often for effect and I'm sure it's grammatically correct.

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127055/came-saw-conquered) is similar, but is to do with the appropriateness, rather than the name, of this contruction.

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/371968/comma-usage-in-parallel-structure-without-conjunctions) asks whether it is acceptable, but not its name.

Comment: [*Asyndeton*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asyndeton)

Comment: @StoneyB This is the answer.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime Agreed, didn't find that. What next?

Comment: @DavidRowthorn The Community user marked it as a duplicate, so we're good.